# @Observable with Custom Encoders/Decoders

Tags: serialization, xcode15, observation

I have a library here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/AgileDB.

It uses custom encoder and decoder to work with SQLite. When using the @Observable macro, the keys are changed and the coding fails. Has anyone done any work to make a custom encoder/decoder work with the @Observable macro?